# Unable to install apache spark on DCOS

Tags: apache-spark, dcos

I installed DC/OS VERSION 1.9.2 on OpenStack.
I try to install apache spark on DC/OS.

```
dcos package install spark
Installing Marathon app for package [spark] version [1.1.0-2.1.1]
Installing CLI subcommand for package [spark] version [1.1.0-2.1.1]
New command available: dcos spark
DC/OS Spark is being installed!
```

But DC/OS dashboard shows that Spark is deploying and task not runing.
Errors showw this messages.

```
I0728 16:43:36.348244 14038 exec.cpp:162] Version: 1.2.2
I0728 16:43:36.656839 14046 exec.cpp:237] Executor registered on agent abf187f4-ad7d-4ead-9437-5cdba4f77bdc-S1
+ export DISPATCHER_PORT=24238
+ DISPATCHER_PORT=24238
+ export DISPATCHER_UI_PORT=24239
+ DISPATCHER_UI_PORT=24239
+ export SPARK_PROXY_PORT=24240
+ SPARK_PROXY_PORT=24240
+ SCHEME=http
+ OTHER_SCHEME=https
+ [[ '' == true ]]
+ export DISPATCHER_UI_WEB_PROXY_BASE=/service/spark
+ DISPATCHER_UI_WEB_PROXY_BASE=/service/spark
+ grep -v '#https#' /etc/nginx/conf.d/spark.conf.template
+ sed s,#http#,,
+ sed -i 's,<PORT>,24240,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/spark.conf
+ sed -i 's,<DISPATCHER_URL>,http://172.16.129.180:24238,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/spark.conf
+ sed -i 's,<DISPATCHER_UI_URL>,http://172.16.129.180:24239,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/spark.conf
+ sed -i 's,<PROTOCOL>,,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/spark.conf
+ [[ '' == true ]]
+ [[ -f hdfs-site.xml ]]
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ exec runsvdir -P /etc/service
+ + mkdirmkdir -p -p /mnt/mesos/sandbox/nginx /mnt/mesos/sandbox/spark

+ exec
+ exec svlogd /mnt/mesos/sandbox/nginx
+ exec svlogd /mnt/mesos/sandbox/spark
nginx: [emerg] could not build the types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 32
nginx: [emerg] could not build the types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 32
nginx: [emerg] could not build the types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 32
nginx: [emerg] could not build the types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 32
nginx: [emerg] could not build the types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 32
```

How to Spark task run on DCOS. 
Thank you .

Comment: I logined to spark docker. I tried changed type_hash_buck_size to 64. Deploy finished. But this process is not cool.

Comment: I checked DCOS log. I guess that deploy is ocmplated , but NGINX in Docker does not run.  DCOS checked spark health, but NGINX does not respond. DCOS recognizes that spark is unheath and kills spark. Spark try to deploy again.  Now, this process is endless.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you uninstalled a former spark installation properly. You have to remove the old zookeeper spark entry (under /exhibitor).

Also check if there are no zombie frameworks in mesos which are blocking the resources for your new deployment. Kill them with:

```
http://MESOSMASTER_URL:5050/master/teardown -d 'frameworkId='<FRAMEWORKID>''
```

Comment: I tried to uninstalled spark, and remove the old zookeeper spark entry. I checked zombie frameworks, I coluld not find it.